# Flutter pass User instance to another state and keep it updated

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a login/registration process and redirect user to a Dashboard view.

So I have this method:

```
Future _redirectToDashboard() async {
    var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(userID: userID),
    );
    Navigator.of(context).push(route);
  }
```

And then call it after `login()` is finished.

```
_register().whenComplete(() => _redirectToDashboard());
```

And then in `Dashboard` I do this:

```
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget
{
  int userID;
  Dashboard({Key key, this.userID}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Dashboard createState() => _DashboardState();
}
```

And use it with:

```
Text('User ID: ${widget.userID}')
```

But then I cannot do this in `Dashboard` class:

```
Dashboard({Key key, this.userID, this.name, this.balance}) : super(key: key);
```

even though I set it in a function above as:

```
builder: (BuildContext context) => new Dashboard(userID: userID, name: name, balance: balance),
```

But it doesn't work. I get an error that `name` for example is not defined Why can I only pass one parameter? And is there a way how can I update the `Dashboard` with new data every time user opens this state?

I read that I should create a seperate `User` class with all properties. But how can I apply it to a dashboard?

Comment: can you post the final code for Dashboard class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you only added constructor parameters, without adding the actual class members.

```dart
class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget
{
  final int userID;
  final String name;
  final String balance;
  Dashboard({Key key, this.userID, this.name, this.balance}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _Dashboard createState() => _DashboardState();
}
```